Override root CSS variable without repeating al properties declarations that consume them
Given the following code, the text color is correctly changed in the nested element after updating the root css variable. Is there a way to avoid repeating the color prop twice and get it automatically re-evaluated inside the nested element?


::root {
--text-color-primary: black;
}

body {
  color: var(--text-color-primary);
}


.myElement {
  --text-color-primary: blue;
  color: var(--text-color-primary); //can we avoid this???
}
<body>
  This is the body text.
  <div class="myElement">This is my element</div>
</body>



EDIT:
The use case for this is the following. We maintain a design system, that comes with a core theme that defines default values for all variables and a list of components and styles that consume them. We want to enable users to customize their components' look and feel by simply overriding all - or part - of those variables in a scoped way, i.e. without affecting their behaviour outside, without the cognitive load of knowing all their usages and without the burden of replacing all of them, which in some cases, can be tedious and ultimately become error-prone (if we add/remove a style that consumes a variable in the DS, users should update their code accordingly).

no you cannot. I also don't see how this would be useful. You should not change a variable but rather use a different variable or set the color correctly in the first place. Variables are not expected change for every element

hi @tacoshy . The use case for this is the following. We maintain a design system, that comes with a core theme that defines default values for all variables. We want to enable users to customize their components' look and feel by simply overriding all or part of those variables in a scoped way, without affecting their outside value and without the cognitive load of knowing all their usages and the burden of replacing all of them, which in some cases, can be tedious and ultimately become error-prone (if we add/remove a property that consumes a variable, users should update their code as well)

You're having an XY issue here. You have a default theme that should be loaded first. A custom theme should simply override the default by either using a different CSS that is loaded afterward or using different names to not mix them up.

@tacoshy I think the "component" part is the important bit here. The way I understand it, the user can use multiple components on a page, but they might want to overwrite the styling for one of those only, and leave the rest in the "default" style the page provides.

exactly @C3roe . The idea is that a product team might want to customize only a portion of a screen by just re-defining the design system variables within the scope of a component (and its children components subtree). A sort of a local patch or "skin". Example: a page that contains multiple branded banners, where each brand has an own palette of basic colors and contain more atomic components from the DS.
